# Asymptotic approximation of random sequences of strictly increasing elements

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability, sequences-and-series, algorithms

I have an assignment to count the number of strictly increasing subarrays within a given array.

An $O(n)$ algorithm exists to this problem, which I have implemented. To make sure my algorithm was correct, I have also written a brute-force code and compared them. The way I did this was to choose a length of a sequence $n$, (array size), and throw inside random integers.

The algorithms did produce the same results, but while toying with it, I noticed something strange. If $x$ is the amount of random integers picked this way and $f(x)$ is the count of such subarrays created in this manner, then:

$$\lim\limits_{x\to\infty} \frac {f(x)}{x} \approx 0.71828...$$

This just cannot be a coincidence. I've ran thousands of simulations with a large size, and this keeps showing. Can anyone explain this? And maybe find a more precise asmptotic approximation?

Comment: That number looks like $e-2 = \sum_{k=2}^\infty \frac1{k!}$. I suspect your observation follows from the fact that a randomly generated $k$-tuple of distinct integers has a $\frac1{k!}$ chance of being an increasing sequence, just by symmetry.